geeting error sql udf datashare not enabled while calling redshift procedure from java using Namedparameter
i am trying to call redshift stored procedure which contain multiple temporary table operation . but calling proc getting error  "sql udf data share not enabled " redshift exception.
i am trying using call redshift procedure using callable statement Named parameter But same exception i got .could you please help me regarding this question
